# CSS not showing in browser

Tags: html, css

My CSS is not showing in my browser, only the HTML is. Everything is linked up correctly (I think) but no browser shows the CSS. Now if I used something like live-server plugin in visual studio code the CSS is displayed correctly and works as intended.

**Here is my css:**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap');

body{
    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

.top{
    text-align: center;
}

header{
    align-items: center;
}

h1 span{
    color: red;
}

p span{
    color: red;
}

p{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.explain{
    color: white;
}
.explain p{
    color: red;
}


.forum-container{
    background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
    margin: 1em 30em 1em 30em;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 3em;
    padding-top: 1.1em;
}

label{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}

input[type="text"]{
    border: solid grey;
    outline: none;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 4em;
    margin-top: 1.1em;
    margin-bottom: 1.1em;
}

input[type="number"]{
    outline: none;
    border: solid grey;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 4em;
    margin-top: 1.1em;
    margin-bottom: 1.1em;
}

input[type="button"]{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1.1em;
    padding-bottom: 1.1em;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 1.1em 1.1em 1.1em 1.1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="button"]:hover{
    background-color: rgb(211, 5, 5);
}
```

Here is the part where I am calling my css file too:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/logo.png"><title>title</title>
</head>
```

I only started learning HTML and css today so if you are taking a look at this and see some things I am doing wrong please do let me know.

Comment: Is `weight` spelled wrong?

Comment: No, ```weight``` is spelt correctly.

Comment: CSS code wont help here, your problem is how are you calling that CSS file in HTML... Look up basic examples of this, and check your paths, they differ from host to host. (local, server etc)

Comment: A [validation check of your css](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator) says all good!

Comment: @ikiK I have just updated my thread to include the code I have used when calling my css file. My css file is located in /css/main.css as I have put in the code.

Comment: add type="text/css"  to it, also try inside your html to show /images/logo.png image, if it dos not shows up, your paths are wrong. research how to fix it.

Comment: do you know how to use developer tools in chrome?  check the network tab, reload the page and see if it is finding your css file.  Where exactly is the css file in your directory? also, what are you using in the backend? php?

Comment: Probably remove the leading '/' from `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">` or add two `..` in front of it... Check your paths! (probably icon too)

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to see the CSS file loaded in the Network tab of your browser?

How to:

> Developer Console > Network

In order for the above to work, open the developer console for your browser (here is a good link to find out for your browser: [Check Opening Browser Developer Console](https://balsamiq.com/support/faqs/browserconsole/))

If the CSS file is showing up in the Network tab, it means your CSS selectors are not correct.

If the CSS file isn't showing up, your path isn't correct. As a test put the entire url (absolute) in the `src`', like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://mywebsite.com/css/main.css">`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue, and upon reviewing my code, I discovered the culprit.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css">
```

The `/` in the `href=""` attribute wasn't necessary since both the HTML file and the CSS file were located in the same folder. Despite the live server rendering the CSS changes, it doesn't guarantee that the path is correctly specified and recognized by the browser. This oversight might also affect other files, such as images. Hence, it's crucial to ensure the accuracy of file paths to prevent such issues.

Answer (score -1):

Change the CSS reference to the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" >
```

Then everything works perfectly fine.

I had that problem as well. Copying and pasting others' codes wasn't helpful, because it still needed some tweaking, nonetheless, I thought CSS won't show up and that was just it.

I use chrome as a console.

The CSS X HTML linking is external if that's not obvious enough.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you would have to use this notation for accessing your css which is inside your folder "./" so in your example it would look like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./images/logo.png">
```

Answer (score -1):

When I was making a website I had the same problem.
First:
Is it updated after a couple hours?
If yes, then it's because your host is slow. CSS files have a slow update time, to check if it's updating slowly: make an offline backup and see if it works.
I couldn't fix my problem so if you're really in a hurry I suggest using `<style></style>` to fix it.

Answer (score -2):

The CSS file link needs to have an attribute of type. So, the final code should look like this  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" "href="/css/main.css">

Comment: `type` is not a requirement for the link tag.